# request function code not executed in Gauge

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, gauge

I am trying to automate website by handling rest api
and I am using gauge to automate this
 and here is sample code

```
const request=require('request');

function test(){
    console.log("outside request");
    request.get(url,(err,res)=>{
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        console.log("inside request");

    }).auth(usr,pswd);
}
step("test api", async function() {
    test();
});
```

output :

```
outside request
```

`inside request` not printed and no error message displayed 
**Extra Information:** the same code gives expected output when it is executed as normal js file i.e. outside gauge.